# Google map Change according to latitude and longitude value change

Tags: php, google-maps

Currently Using This Javascript -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script language='javascript'> 
    window.onload = function() { 
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $long; ?>);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: latlng,
            zoom: 11,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Set lat/lon values for this property',
            draggable: true
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(a) {
            console.log(a);
                document.getElementById("Latitude").value = this.getPosition().lat();
                document.getElementById("Longitude").value = this.getPosition().lng();  

            });
        };
     </script>
```

It works fine but I want the Map location to change when the Latitude And Longitude Value's change.

Answer (score 1):

if you use jQuery this is quite simple.

```
$('#Latitude,#Longitude').click(function(){
    var lat = $('#Latitude').val();
    var lng = $('#Longitude').val();

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng);

    map.panTo( latlng );

}
```

Comment: I actually want the draggable pointer on map and Want to change location on map if user enter latitude and longitude manually .

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html> 
    <body>
    <input type="number"  id="txtlat" name="txtlat" placeholder="Latitude">
     <input type="number" id="txtlng" name="txtlng" placeholder="Longitude">
     <button onclick="fncheck()">Click</button>
    </body>
   <script>
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
  </script>
  </html>
```